# What is 'DispatchedHandler' and how to use it in ABI?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime

Using this method with C++/CX is easy:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    // Your UI update code goes here!
});
```

But I'm working with ABI and then things get more comples. The 'RunAsync' method of

`ABI::Windows::UI::Core::ICoreDispatcher`

takes as a second parameter

`ABI::Windows::UI::Core::IDispatchedHandler`

What the is this? Here is it declaration in

`windows.ui.core.h`:

```
namespace ABI {
        namespace Windows {
            namespace UI {
                namespace Core {

                    MIDL_INTERFACE("D1F276C4-98D8-4636-BF49-EB79507548E9")
                    IDispatchedHandler : public IUnknown
                    {
                    public:
                        virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke( void) = 0;

                    };

                    extern const __declspec(selectany) IID & IID_IDispatchedHandler = __uuidof(IDispatchedHandler);


                }  /* end namespace */
            }  /* end namespace */
        }  /* end namespace */
    }  /* end namespace */
```

How can I store this nice lambda code in 'CX' to this strange interface (which seems to not be a WinRT component and inherits IUnkown and not IInspectable).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class that implements `IDispatchedHandler`, e.g.:

```
class MyDispatchedHandler : public RuntimeClass<
    RuntimeClassFlags<WinRtClassicComMix>,
    IDispatchedHandler>
{
public:
    // Needed for MakeAndInitialize.
    HRESULT RuntimeClassInitialize()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    // IDispatchedHandler members.
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke()
    {
        // TODO: Write here the code you need to run in the UI thread.

        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

Then, pass create an instance of this class and pass it to `RunAsync()`, i.e.:

```
// For simplicity, I omitted error validation.

ComPtr<MyDispatchedHandler> myDispatchedHandler;
MakeAndInitialize<MyDispatchedHandler>(&myDispatchedHandler);

ComPtr<IAsyncAction> asyncAction;

dispatcher->RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority::CoreDispatcherPriority_Normal,
    myDispatchedHandler.Get(),
    &asyncAction);
```